# How to bind radio button values from database in edit form in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have created a form **from.blade.php** for both create **create.balde.php** and edit **edit.blade.php**. I'm using that form to perform the two action but I'm facing a problem with retrieving data and displaying it for radio buttons .. knowing that when I go to create action the radio buttons will be as default.

This the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            {{-- {{ ($news->status=="1")? "checked" : "" }} --}}
            <input class="form-check-input" {{ $page->status == '1' ? 'checked' : '' }} type="radio" name="status"
                   id="exampleRadios1" value="0" checked>
            Status is off
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="check"></span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" {{ $page->status == '1' ? 'checked' : '' }} name="status"
                   id="exampleRadios2" value="1">
            Status is on
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="check"></span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This `{{ $page->status == '1' ? 'checked' : '' }}` works fine for edit 
but when I go to create.blade.php, I get this error:

> Undefined variable: page (View:
>   C:\Users\PC\Desktop\khaleej_aden\resources\views\pages\includes\form.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\Users\PC\Desktop\khaleej_aden\resources\views\pages\includes\form.blade.php)

but if I removed those lines the **create.blade.php**  works perfectly.
so what can I change in `{{ $page->status == '1' ? 'checked' : '' }}` to make it work for both create and update?

Comment: Please can you add your controller code for the `create` and `edit` routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and less ugly way is to pass an empty Page instance from your controller to the page, so something like this:

```
$page = new Page;

return view('create', compact('page'));
```

This way you can avoid checks each time you want to use the page variable within the view.

Answer (score 0):

You also can change the code to check the object before check the status

```
{{ (isset($page->status) && $page->status == '1') ? 'checked' : '' }}
```